# angularjs, spring boot, spring security oauth2, authorization fails ONLY when app started from command line

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have Spring-boot ui-server which include Angular single page app and I have third party authorization oauth2 provider. My spring-boot app redirects to login oauth2 provider page, got "code" and obtain access_token.

I have two problems:

1. I successfully get access_token but can not get userInfo, auth server respond 500 (I have no acess to auth server to debug something, so only got the 500 error in response). I found a solution: just create class ResourceServerTokenServices exactly like CustomUserInfoTokenServices and put it Bean into @Configuration class:

   @Configuration
   public class Conf {

   ```
   @Autowired
   private ResourceServerProperties sso;
   @Bean

   public ResourceServerTokenServices myUserInfoTokenServices() {
       return new CustomUserInfoTokenServices(sso.getUserInfoUri(), sso.getClientId());
   }
   ```

   }

Security Properties:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      accessTokenUri: https://authserver/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://authserver/oauth/authorize
      clientId: client
      clientSecret: secret
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://authserver/user/get?format=json
      preferTokenInfo: false
```

It is very weird but it works! I don't understand why the standard configuration doesn't work.

2. Next problem with starting the app.

a) start from IDE - app started succcessful, security works fine

b) start from command line by "spring-boot:run" - app started successful, security works fine

c) start from command line by "java -jar" - app started successful, but I got "401 Unauthorized" and call stack:

```
2016-02-24 13:16:50.378 DEBUG 4264 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] g.c.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider : Retrieving token from *****/oauth/token
2016-02-24 13:16:50.532 DEBUG 4264 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] g.c.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider : Encoding and sending form: {grant_type=[authorization_code], code=[160224ACS2gmbxvr1581], redirect_uri=[http://****/login]}
2016-02-24 13:16:50.907 DEBUG 4264 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] uth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Could not obtain access token
2016-02-24 13:16:50.907 DEBUG 4264 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] uth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
```

So authorization fails *only* when the app is started from the command line. Maybe spring-boot fat jar packaging doesn't work correctly?

Comment: Did you try to verify that the packaged .jar file contains your application settings file? Remember that a .jar file is just a zipped directory so you can easily uncompress it and inspect.

Comment: Yes, packaged jar contains file application.yml with all settings! And first action in authentification chain - redirect to oauth2 server (auth server urls already in application.yml) login page, goes correctly, but problem only with obtaining token. When I switch back again to start app by spring-boot: run or run from NetBeans all auth process goes successfull and got access_token